# Laravel PDF: No block-level parent found. Not good

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5, dompdf

My code was just working fine until today. I did not change anything but suddenly my pdf code not working. I am using `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` this package in `laravel 5.2`.

I deleted my local project and download from the live server but still, this problem occurs on my local computer. My live project works fine with this code.

Here is my code

```
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadView('back_end.pdf_template.make_invoice', ['order_info' =>$order_info, 'order_details' => $order_details]);
return $pdf->stream('inv-' . $order_info->invoice_id . '.pdf');
```

I am getting this error
[image]

I also try `enable_html5_parser` set to `true`. And after this, I am getting another error
[image]

Answer (score 12):

## No block-level parent found. Not good. This is a parser error

hello friend,

It can be fixed if you delete spaces between the html, head and body tags, as shown below:

**It works:**

```
<html><head>
...
</head><body>
...
</body></html>
```

**It fails:**

```
<html>
  <head>
  ...
  </head>

  <body>
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

I had the same problem, with the same laravel version, when I updated my php
from 5.6 to 7.0 version.

When I tried to generate the pdf file the message was thrown:

***No block-level parent found. Not good.***

This solution was found in this github page

https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/1582#issuecomment-359448550

I hope I have been useful

Comment: Thank you! I had a site that was working for years (not Laravel, custom PHP) and suddenly stopped working. This fixed it. Any ideas _why_ this works?

Comment: @texelate, I think it's a problem with the parser when it finds the newline character, I do not know exactly. fortunately I found this solution, I lost some time to solve this problem.

Comment: I faced this issue after upgrading php version to php 7. With this html structure change, solved my problems. not needed to upgrade dompdf. Thanks

Comment: is there other solution apart from this? this seems not to be of help

Comment: Sorry @AbdurRahmanTurawa, I don't know any other solution. I spent a lot of time with this problem and luckily I found the solution in the above mentioned link. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, for me it was caused by the `html` tag not being detected as a block-level parent.
Had to add the following CSS to fix it:

```
html, body {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Worked in Laravel 8. Thank you.